# ArcMap - Export raster symbology to a raster function template programmatically

Tags: raster, arcmap, arcobjects, arcgis-10.2

I would like to programmatically export symbology for a raster dataset as a raster function template xml file, as can be done by clicking the export button in the symbology tab of the layer properties dialog in ArcMap 10.2.2.

I wish to do this in a batch environment (outside of ArcMap) using ArcObjects.

---

Subsequently ESRI Canada support advised that the export required above is not exposed in the ArcObjects API. However I have found that xml serializing the RasterRenderer for the layer, [snippet here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57651/how-to-set-min-and-max-value-for-stretchtype-esrirasterstretch-percentminimumma/129873#129873), does in fact produce the same content as seen as the value for the Renderer variable in the manually / UI exported raster function template (!).

I'm trying to bring the symbology across for individual rasters after they are added to a mosaic dataset. Color maps seem to come across, but stretches don't. So after realizing the above, I'm working on wrapping the RasterRender serialized XML to be a raster function template and then applying it.

Comment: There is sample code in the Help file (TestNDVICustomFunction) that uses the _IXMLSerialize_ interface to serialize it into XML. What I could not work out from the code sample was how one got an _IRasterFunctionTemplate_ object from an existing raster created from a series of raster functions.

Comment: @Hornbydd that looks like enough to post as an answer.